# error: activity not declared in AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

My AndroidManifest.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-feature android:name="com.softbank.hardware.pepper" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TammyApp">
        <activity android:name=".ui.categories.CategoriesActivity">

        </activity>

#         <activity android:name=".activities.Muse.muse_pick_duration" />

        <activity android:name=".activities.Welcome">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".activities.SpeechService" />
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

/////////////////////////////////
muse_pick_duration.kt:

```
package com.tammy.tammyapp.activities.Muse

import com.tammy.tammyapp.R
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.tammy.tammyapp.activities.TutorialActivity


abstract class muse_pick_duration : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContentView(R.layout.muse_pick_duration)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
museHome.kt:

```
package com.tammy.tammyapp.activities.Muse

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.tammy.tammyapp.R
import com.tammy.tammyapp.activities.TutorialActivity

abstract class MipniHome : AppCompatActivity(){
    //abstract val muse_pick_duration: Unit

    abstract val muse_pick_duration: Unit
    abstract val savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    fun onCreate() {
        setContentView(R.layout.muse_home)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            val Intent = Intent(this, muse_pick_duration::class.java)
            startActivity(Intent)
        }
    }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
muse_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    tools:context=".museHome">

    // main menu button
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="259dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#3F51B5"
        android:text="Main Menu"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    // back button
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#3F51B5"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    // next button
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#3F51B5"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Press &quot;BACK&quot; to return to the previous screen"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Press &quot;NEXT&quot; when you are ready to continue"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="508dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="237dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="266dp"
        android:text="Welcome to MIPNI,"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:text="your musical companion app!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="502dp"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/music" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////

I attached my code above that includes a button(button3) trying to open another activity(muse_pick_duration) and the AndroidManifest.xml.

The bolded activity is the one that says is not declared but I did declare it... IDK what is going on. Can someone please help?!

I tried so invalidating the cache and restaring. I also tried syncing project with gradle files but mone of that worked. I have two activities: muse_pick_duration and museHome and both are in kotlin...

Comment: Show me your logcat error plz

Comment: there is no logcat error. I tried making a button that opens up a new activity. That new activity never opens up, but an error pops up saying that the new activity wasn't declared in the .XML...

Comment: Kindly share screenshot of Android Studio where we can see your java packaging and layout name or share complete code

Comment: file:///Users/srinipatil/Documents/Screen%20Shot%202022-12-22%20at%2010.32.47%20PM.png

Comment: does this help you understand my problem better?

Comment: Share your code please, if possible provide git link so that i can review and can tell you about the actual problem.

Comment: I am not sure how to send you the link as I am working with another person and my code isn't working.... I tried to attach the parts of the code that I think are causing the problem.